# How to call <listener> function manually?

Tags: flutter, listener

I have the FocusNode like this:

```
fn1.addListener(
      () {
        if (!fn1.hasFocus) {
          setState(
            () {
              _descriptionFieldShowSuffix = false;
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

And I would like to call  function in above manually, for example, from another controler:

```
nameController!.addListener(
      () {
        fn1.notifyListeners();
      },
    );
```

What is a right way for this issue? As I know, notifyListeners() is not good idea for my Widget.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the unfocus() method on the node:

```
fn1.addListener(
  () {
    if (!fn1.hasFocus) {
      setState(() {
        _descriptionFieldShowSuffix = false;
      });
    }
  },
);

// Trigger listener manually
nameController!.addListener(() {
  fn1.unfocus(); // This will trigger the listener attached to fn1
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But I need to keep field focused : (